# How to use rewrite rule for Node exporter under Nginx Reverse Proxy?

Tags: nginx, redirect, proxy, reverse-proxy, prometheus-node-exporter

I have a usecase where node exporter is running under reverse proxy. Here is the snippet of my current configuration:

```
    location /node_exporter {
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:9100/metrics;
    }
```

This is running fine, but I want to implement it without metrics subpath, for which I did this change:

```
    location /node_exporter {
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:9100/;
    }
```

It is opening the initial page of node exporter with metrics button, but when clicked on it, redirects to `/metrics` instead of `/node_exporter/metrics` which inturn gives 404.

Please suggest on how to use the rewrite rule for this usecase.

Comment: Any success with this? I'm stuck in the same problem

Answer (score 2):

The following site configuration should be enough

```
location /node_exporter {  
  proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:9100/;
}
```

as long the telemetry path is changed when starting the node_exporter

`./node_exporter/node_exporter --web.telemetry-path="/node_exporter/metrics"`

Comment: It must be as:
location /node_exporter {  
  proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:9100;
}